# Merge data from similar worksheet across multiple Excel Files

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2013

I've got multiple MS Excel files in hundreds every file has multiple worksheets similar in structure and schemas under a particular folder. Every type of worksheet has pretty much following structure(range of columns may differ); 
e.g. department worksheet may look like this

```
Column A  | Column B  | Column C 

Header A  | Header B  | Header C

[value]   |  [value]  |  [value]
```

I want to merge all department worksheets from multiple excel files into one big depart worksheet e.g.

```
Column A  | Column B  | Column C 

Header A  | Header B  | Header C

[value]   |  [value]  |  [value]
[value1]      |  [value1]  |  [value1]
[value2]      |  [value2]  |  [value2]
[value3]      |  [value3]  |  [value3]...
```

What would be the automated way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: But to get you started with your own code, you can create a new wb for your master book. Open each file one at a time, append the data to your master workbook then close it. Then rinse and repeat until all your workbooks have been completed.

Comment: While you may think you have one question, in reality you have multiple. Meaning this is way too broad for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs it is simple question don't take words literally please. let me know if you are not able to understand any part of it

Comment: Are all your department sheets called "department"? Is this the only worksheet you are interested in bringing into your new spreadsheet?

Comment: @Xabier not every file has department along with few different ones like school and class etc, I want to keep them in that format when I merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be pretty close.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Also, see this.

If you want to copy all cells from the worksheet or from A2 till the last cell on the worksheet.Then replace the code above with this

```
With mybook.Worksheets(1)
    FirstCell = "A2"
    Set SourceRange = .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells))
    'Test if the row of the last cell >= then the row of the FirstCell
    If RDB_Last(1, .Cells) < .Range(FirstCell).Row Then
         Set SourceRange = Nothing
    End If
End With
```

Finally, consider using the AddIn from the link below.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]

Comment: I already tried this tool but this one puts data in columns forms instead of rows that I'm trying to achieve the format above. Any thoughts on how we can have the above format preferably per sheet?